# Communicate with host machine in instrumented tests

Tags: android, android-instrumentation

I have the application which doing some really dirty things with wifi. App looking when some wifi point will appear nearby then switch device to this wifi access point, do some request to the server that is placed inside this network and switch back to previos access point.

I want to implement some instrumented test to ensure that app working correctly. Problem is: I need to tell host machine to switch on/off that network during execution of test cases.
Could you please suggest if it is even possible?

Thanks in advice. Anatolii

Comment: to mock requests/responses try to use MockWebServer.

Comment: problem is i want to check network layer as well :(